# How to Change The Default Value of RS4 Class Attribute - rpy2

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rpy2

I am mapping a class RS4 in python by doing the following:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro

class MapTOS4(ro.methods.RS4):
    """
    writing a child class to map to S4 reference class in python
    """
    def LoadFile(self, filename):
        """access the LoadFile method of SlicedData class"""

        return ro.baseenv['$'](self, 'LoadFile')(filename)
    
    def fileSliceSize(self):
        """access the class attribute or field""" 
        return ro.baseenv['$'](self, 'fileSliceSize')
    
mql = importr('MatrixEQTL')
data = MapTOS4(mql.SlicedData())
print(data.fileSliceSize())
```

When executing the above code, I got the following `[1] 1000` which is expected because in that particular package the class field/attribute `fileSliceSize` its default value is set to 1000. However, I am trying to reset or change the value of that class attribute to 2000.

In R you can easily do that, with the following straightforward code:

```
data$fileSliceSize = 2000
```

How can I achieve this based on my implementation in Python?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, the `data$fileSliceSize = 2000` operation is just a syntactic sugar for calling a `$<-` function with three arguments (*object*, *key*, *value*):

```
library(MatrixEQTL)
data = SlicedData()

`$<-`(data, 'fileSliceSize', 2000)
# SlicedData object. For more information type: ?SlicedData
# Number of columns: 0 
# Number of rows: 0 
# Data is stored in 0 slices
```

the same way as access by `data$fileSliceSize` is a syntactic sugar for:

```
`$`(data, 'fileSliceSize')
# [1] 2000
```

The bacticks are used to escape the special characters in the function name - you could call any R function with backticks:

```
`print`('text')
# [1] "text"
```

See more in the the [Extract chapter](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) of R's documentation.

Therefore, in rpy2 you could simply do:

```
ro.baseenv['$<-'](data, 'fileSliceSize', 2000)
```

However, I would recommend trying a more "pythonic" approach (docstrings omitted for brevity):

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro


# assigning these R operators here will make the code easier to read
# and provide a (negligible in this case) performance increase.
get_r_attribute = ro.baseenv['$']
set_r_attribute = ro.baseenv['$<-']


class MapTOS4(ro.methods.RS4): 

    def __init__(self, r_obj, file_slice_size=2000): 
        super().__init__(r_obj) 
        self.file_slice_size = file_slice_size

    def load_file(self, filename):
        return get_r_attribute(self, 'LoadFile')(filename)

    @property
    def file_slice_size(self):
        return get_r_attribute(self, 'fileSliceSize') 

    @file_slice_size.setter 
    def file_slice_size(self, value): 
        set_r_attribute(self, 'fileSliceSize', value)


mql = importr('MatrixEQTL') 
data = MapTOS4(mql.SlicedData()) 
print(data.file_slice_size)
# prints 2000
data.file_slice_size = 3000
print(data.file_slice_size)
# prints 3000

# setting a value initialization:
data = MapTOS4(mql.SlicedData(), file_slice_size=4000)
print(data.file_slice_size)
# prints 4000
```

Comment: Thank you so much @krassowski for your answer, it works, now can I am able to get and set class attributes. Is there a way I can set and get the attributes without using the 'get_r_attribute = ro.baseenv['$'] and set_r_attribute = ro.baseenv['$<-']?

Comment: Why don't you like get_r_attribute and set_r_attribute?

Comment: I really like it but I want to see if there is a way to make it more Pythonic?

Comment: If I were to modify something, I would keep the `get_r_attribute`/`set_r_attribute` (they explain what is going on), but experiment with using `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` special methods to automate the process of getting R properties of the object; this would require extra work for properties with dot in name. Not sure how much it would help.

Comment: I got it, well then I will take your suggestion and keep them. Thank you so much for your answer, I voted thump up and will accept your answer.